# How to pass multiple lines as an input to stdin (Python)

Tags: python, eclipse, stdout, stdin

Suppose the sample input is this:

```
"1 2 3"
"hello"
"hi there"
"x y z"
"5 6 7"
```

This should be passed into *stdin* and the output should simply print them to *stdout*

I have the following code in *sample.py*, and I'm using Eclipse as my IDE.

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    print line
```

If I'm using a command line, I might be able to do something like

```
python sample.py "1 2 3 \n hello"
```

to pass the input to stdin. But how should I do this on Eclipse(when there are multiple lines that should be inputted into stdin)?

---

Since I didn't know how to do this, I simply put the lines into a txt file and read from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Windows,

1. Add Python directory to the environment variable PATH (ex. C:\Python27)
2. put all the lines into some text file (ex. input.txt should contain "hello \n hello")
3. run `cmd`
4. go to the directory where the source code and input file are
5. run `python sample.py < input.txt`

Then you get an output in `stdout`!